# Como evitar que uma div saia da pagina, quando outra div mudar de tamanho?

Tags: javascript, html, css, div

Minha pagina tem basicamente duas `divs`, uma a direita e outra a esquerda, as duas estao com `style="position: fixed;"`, ou seja, se eu rolo a pagina, essas duas `divs` ficam lado a lado, fixas, sempre visíveis.

Mas quando a `div` da esquerda recebe texto, ela muda seu tamanho fica mais larga. Isso "empurra" a `div` da direita mais ainda para a direita e consequentemente para fora da janela do navegador. Logo, uma parte do seu conteúdo não pode mais ser visto.

Como fazer a `div` da direita ter sua borda direita menor que o limite da janela do navegador, como por exemplo fazer essa  `div` ficar mais fina e mais "magra", impedindo que ela "vaze" para fota da tela?

Comment: Amigo, tente utilizar style="width:50%;" nas duas divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, **Roberval**!

Utilize o **box-sizing** *trave* os tamanhos com a **porcentagem** desejada.
[Veja as dicas no CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Coloquei no **JSFiddle** p/ você poder testar também!
[JSFiddle | https://jsfiddle.net/romulobastos/awnonopr/](https://jsfiddle.net/romulobastos/awnonopr/)

---

#### Segue o código:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; }
    h1 { font-size: 21px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2); }
    #container {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #divEsquerda, #divDireita {
      position: fixed;
     height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 2%;
      color: #fff;
      overflow: auto;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;  
    }
    #divEsquerda{ width: 30%; background: #246; left: 0; }
    #divDireita { width: 70%; background: #369; right: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <!-- esquerda -->
      <div id="divEsquerda">
        <h1>Conteúdo da Esquerda</h1>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
      
      <!-- direita -->
      <div id="divDireita">
        <h1>Conteúdo da Direita</h1>
        <p>...</p>    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Abraço!

Comment: Romulo, utilize o recurso do SO para colocar blocos de código na resposta, visto que a disponibilidade do link externo não pode ser garantida.

Comment: Pronto, @Marciano.Andrade. Obrigado pelo comentário!

Comment: valeu @Marciano Andrade, resolvidoooo!!   brigadao!
quem me dera todo mundo fosse assim tao claro nas responstas e tao completo!!!

Comment: Ainda mais .. quando a gente, nao sabe bem como perguntar... E POR isso mesmo esta fazendo uma pergunta....  rsrsr  logo eh claro que se nao  sei .. vou fazer um pergunta esquizita... neh??

brigadao mais uma vez

Comment: @RobervalSena山本 Não existe pergunta esquisita :) se tiver dúvidas pode perguntar amigo, mas quem respondeu sua pergunta não fui eu, mas sim o romulobastos :D apenas editei a resposta para ter o snippet ali. Se você é novo na comunidade, sugiro que você leia o [tour]

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade obrigado pela edição! Eu sabia que existia o recurso, mas só agora pude ver como é feito.

Roberval Sena, as vezes não é tão fácil explicar de forma textual o problema que temos (principalmente tratando-se de layout). Mas, a ideia do SO é tirar dúvidas e compartilhar conhecimento. Sua dúvida pode ser uma luz no fim do túnel p/ alguém que tenha esse mesmo "problema", no futuro. Abs!

Comment: ooo @romulobastos   brigadao pelaajuda!  ainda estou me acostumando com esse boot strap!!  voce resolveu meu problema!  

valeu muitooo!